# Python keeps escape character in variable

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to connect to SQL Server using PyODBC.

```
connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

The `username` should be `"MYCOMPANY\username"` so, I have set the variables `username` like this: `username = "MYCOMPANY\\username"`.

The problem is that im getting this error :

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYCOMPANY\\username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MYCOMPANY\\username'. (18456)")
```

I don't understand why the string keeps the "\\".

Anyone can help me up with that please ?

Comment: The variable has no problems, its just python trying to be `helpful` and showing you where the `\` is in the string.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use an AD account like it's a SQL authentication account; that doesn't work. Either use a SQL Authentication Login or a Trusted Connection. Even *if* Python displayed `MYCOMPANY\username` the real problem won't change. You can't pass a Username and Password for an AD account in a connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.encode` then `.decode`:

```
username.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```